# Log to Console and Should be equal issues in Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, robotframework, selenium2library

I have below application under test.
[image]

I am using Selenium2Library-Python-RobotFramework.
Below is my code where I am fetching the expected price with the help of xpath. For original price I have already set the variables in variable.robot.

```
${ExpectedPriceProductAPrice} =   Get Text   xpath=//span[@id='Price']
sleep  2
Log To Console    Price is  ${ExpectedPriceProductAPrice}
${ExpectedPriceProductACount} =   Get Text   xpath=//span[@id='Count']
sleep  2
Log To Console    Count is   ${ExpectedPriceProductACount}

should be equal   ${ExpectedPriceProductAPrice}   ${OriginalPriceProductAPrice}
should be equal   ${ExpectedPriceProductACount}   ${OriginalPriceProductACount}
should be equal   ${ExpectedPriceProductBPrice}   ${OriginalPriceProductBPrice}
should be equal   ${ExpectedPriceProductBCount}   ${OriginalPriceProductBCount}
```

I am facing two issues :

1. Values are not getting log to console.
2. If ***should be equal*** is failed for first statement then it is not moving ahead to check all other ***should be equal*** conditions

Comment: As for 'Log to console,' - it should take one argument for the message to print. But as you have several spaces after `is`, then your variable is counted as the following argument and not part of the message. You need just to remove extra space(s). E.g.  Should be `Log To Console     Count is ${ExpectedPriceProductACount}`